# Airprint a pdf page

Tags: ios, objective-c, pdf, airprint

I need to print a couple of pages from a PDF with airprint, (and adding a over image to them)
I know how to print a whole pdf, but what I need is to print just the pages selected by the user,

It should be something like

```
[printPages:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:1,2,5,6,9,11]]
```

So I can print an only document with those PDF pages

And I would need to add some overlay image to the pages :D

Do you know if is it possible??

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally created this function

```
-(void) splitPdf:(NSArray*) pages andNewFilePath:(NSString*)newFilePath andShouldRotate:(BOOL) shouldRotate andShouldPrintHoles:(BOOL)shouldPrintHoles{

    UIImage *holes;

    if(shouldRotate)    holes = [UIImage imageNamed:@"holes_rotated.png"];
    else                holes = [UIImage imageNamed:@"holes.png"];


    //create empty pdf file;
    UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToFile(newFilePath, CGRectMake(0, 0, 792, 612), nil);

    CGPDFDocumentRef templateDocument = mPdf;

    //get amount of pages in template
    size_t count = CGPDFDocumentGetNumberOfPages(templateDocument);

    //for each page in template
    for(int i = 0; i< [pages count]; i = i+2){
        //get bounds of template page

        int pageNumber = [((NSNumber*)[pages objectAtIndex:i]) intValue];
        if (pageNumber <= count){

            CGPDFPageRef templatePage   = CGPDFDocumentGetPage(templateDocument,pageNumber);
            CGPDFPageRef templatePage2  = CGPDFDocumentGetPage(templateDocument,pageNumber+1);

            CGRect templatePageBounds = CGPDFPageGetBoxRect(templatePage, kCGPDFCropBox);

            //create empty page with corresponding bounds in new document
            //UIGraphicsBeginPDFPageWithInfo(templatePageBounds, nil);
            float margin = templatePageBounds.size.width*MARGIN_PROPORTION;
            CGRect newRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, templatePageBounds.size.width + margin, templatePageBounds.size.height*A4_PROPORTION + margin);
            UIGraphicsBeginPDFPageWithInfo(newRect, nil);
            CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

            CGContextSaveGState(context);
            if(shouldRotate){
                CGContextTranslateCTM( context, 0.5f * templatePageBounds.size.width, 0.5f * templatePageBounds.size.height) ;
                CGContextRotateCTM(context, radians(90));
                CGContextTranslateCTM( context, -0.5f * templatePageBounds.size.width, -0.5f * templatePageBounds.size.height) ;
            }

            //flip context due to different origins
            if(!shouldRotate){
                CGContextTranslateCTM(context,75, templatePageBounds.size.height + 130);
                CGContextScaleCTM(context, 0.75, -0.75);
            }
            else{
                CGContextTranslateCTM(context,-100, templatePageBounds.size.height - 70);
                CGContextScaleCTM(context, 0.75, -0.75);
            }

            //Center the image with margins
            if(!shouldRotate)    CGContextTranslateCTM(context, margin*0.5f, -margin*A4_PROPORTION);
            else                 CGContextTranslateCTM(context, margin*A4_PROPORTION,margin*0.5f);



            CGContextDrawPDFPage(context, templatePage);  //copy content of template page on the corresponding page in new file

            if(!shouldRotate) CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0,538);
            else              CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 538,0);

            CGContextDrawPDFPage(context, templatePage2);


            CGContextRestoreGState(context);              //Restore state

            /* Here you can do any drawings */
            if(shouldPrintHoles){
                CGContextMoveToPoint(context, 0, 0);
                if(!shouldRotate) {
                    [holes drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(0, ((templatePageBounds.size.height*A4_PROPORTION+margin) * 0.5f) - holes.size.height*0.5f)];
                }
                else{
                    [holes drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(((templatePageBounds.size.width*A4_PROPORTION+margin) * 0.5f) - holes.size.width*0.5f,0)];
                }

            }
        }
        else{
            NSLog(@"Page to split is bigger than number of pages of the document");
        }
    }

    UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();
}
```